# How can I use enviroments variables in Cloud Run whit continuous implementation?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I am using Cloud Run and I want to active the continued implementation whit Github but obviously, I can't upload my env variables so, what can I use

I can't put It when I use "Implement and edit a new version" because it doesn't go to continue, I have to open It click it, and fill the env

I can't use ENV on my Dockerfile because I have to upload it on my Github

I can't use replace it on cloud Build because I am using a Dockerfile and this option is only for `cloudbuild.yml` (and I don't know how to create it I only know docker :)

Maybe I can edit the yalm on Cloud run I I am not sure if that is a good option

Maybe I can pass if I use `gcloud build` but I have to click on "Implement and edit a new version" and It is not continuous implementation

My Dockerfile if you want to help me to transform it on a `cloudbuild.yml`

```
FROM node:15

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

ENV ENV production

ENV PORT 3000

ENV API_URL https://api.mysite.com

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: How did you configure the integration with Github? can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

On [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values), I found how to create the cloudbuild.yalm to continuous integration

```yaml
 steps:
 # Build the container image
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
 # Push the container image to Container Registry
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api:$COMMIT_SHA']
 # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args:
   - 'run'
   - 'deploy'
   - 'api'
   - '--image'
   - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api:$COMMIT_SHA'
   - '--region'
   - 'us-east1'
   - '--platform'
   - 'managed'
 images:
 - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api:$COMMIT_SHA'
```

You have to change API for the name of your service

After, I put on "Implement and edit a new version" and put the environment variables

And all the continuous implementations going to have the same environments variables that I put when I implement a new version.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing on any environment variables into the service.

`gcloud beta run deploy --help` check for `--set-env-vars`.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args:
   - 'run'
   - 'deploy'
   - 'api'
   - '--image'
   - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api:$COMMIT_SHA'
   - '--region'
   - 'us-east1'
   - '--platform'
   - 'managed'
   - '--set-env-vars'
   - 'API_URL=${_API_URL}'

You can use substitutions in the build trigger: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values
```